# PCB design of crystal/oscillator ok in this way?

Tags: pcb, oscillator, stm32, crystal

I'm working on a 4-Layer PCB design for my quadrocopter. I'm using a STM32F407 and I need the 32 khz and 8 Mhz crystal.
Is the pcb design of my crystal OK?

My layer order:

- Sig1
- VDD
- VSS
- Sig2

[image: pcb]
(please draw your corrections in if possible)

Comment: Depending on Crystal uW power limits, 8MHz may need a series R on output >1K. I assume your library shows the two caps as 603R chips.

Comment: yes my lib shows them as R, because I was to lazy to change that. I like to use the rounded pad shape for my caps too.

Comment: Best to import a better library

Answer (score 1):

I would return the ground connections directly to the closest ground lead on the MCU via a pair of tracks.

Comment: The VIAS at the load-caps are GND vias, is this what you mean?

Comment: No. They connect to the ground plane.

Comment: Like this ? http://postimage.org/image/vyweayrs1/

Comment: That's right. Put the ground via on the other side of the lead.

Comment: Can I ask why separating from ground plane? I'm afraid to create an antenna.

Comment: To avoid return currents from other interfaces.